# Can't Save State of Variable inside Parse.com Callback

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface, parse-platform

I'm having trouble retaining the contents of an arraylist of which I populated through a background thread by querying the Parse database. Below is my code. I make an arraylist to be used/sent by intents to other activities, but even though I try to save it in the query it doesn't retain its content.

```
onCreate(){

    ArrayList<FunObject> over = new ArrayList<FunObject>();
    separateMethod();
    //over.size() is still equal to 0.
}

separateMethod() {

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> players, ParseException e){
            if (players != null && players.size()>0 ){
                ArrayList<PlayerInfo> temp = new ArrayList<PlayerInfo>();
                for (ParseObject f : players) { 
                    temp.add(new PlayerInfo (f.getString("name"), f.getString("champion"), f.getString("summoner1"), f.getString("summoner2"), "mid", f.getString("kills") + " / " + f.getString("deaths") + " / " + f.getString("assists")));
                }
                over = temp           
                //This line, I try to set value of my over arraylist, but it
                //doesnt save when I leave the query         
            } else {
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the query runs on another thread that finishes AFTER your `onCreate()` method finishes, how long after will depend on network issues and query complexity.

What you'll need to do is call another method after setting `over = temp`, possibly marshalling it to the main UI thread, to let the UI or other code know that `over` is now populated.

Comment: Thanks! Couple questions, are the query and done method being run in a background thread? Also, I made a separate method trying to use context.over = temp, but context.over isn't accepted. How do you suggest I go about using another method inside the done method?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by utilizing an AsyncTask instead. Essentially I did the query in the background thread, and sent the info taken from the "doInBackground" into the "post" method. Since the "post" method is done in the main thread I can save the state of the variable inside there without losing it.